# Value stored in a variable is different than what is returned by the right hand side of '='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, rack

If I execute

```
env['rack.request.cookie_string'].split('\; ')
```

I get the expected result (array of strings). I have a line of code like this in my controller action:

```
foo = env['rack.request.cookie_string'].split('\; ')
```

When I stop with byebug just after that line, `foo` contains the entire cookie string `env['rack.request.cookie_string']`. What is going on?

Comment: What is the result of `p env['rack.request.cookie_string']`?

Comment: The result is the string including all cookie values.

Comment: Could it be that byebug just hasn't evaluated that line yet? How about adding another line after `foo=..` and add byebug after this line. What happens now?

Comment: @BryanOemar The same. The issue isn't probably just with byebug because I get errors during normal runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to use `split("\; ")` instead of `split('\; ')`.